# Intl.NumberFormat как изменить symbol?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'RUB' }).format(number));
// → 123 456,79 руб.
```

Как "руб." заменить на что-то свое?

Comment: Локаль переделать я не умею, но можно regex применить

Comment: Вот здесь хорошее обсуждение - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного изучив предметную область, мне кажется, что это пока не представляется возможным. В спецификации к API для Intl ([ECMAScript Internationalization API Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0)) говорится, что локализация символов валюты зависит от имплементации, а в качестве таковой многие вендоры используют [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) - унифицированную базу для интернационализации приложений. Спецификация не описывает никаких способов для передачи собственных символов, да и поковырявшись в Shim [ibm-js/ecma402](https://github.com/ibm-js/ecma402/blob/master/Intl.js) и [исходниках v8](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/b104a67ef0a50beab2dc85a6ac5732c696d07698/src/i18n.js) не видно, чтобы они дополнительно давали такую возможность.

Сам API по умолчанию предоставляет три вида отображения "символа" через опцию `currencyDisplay`:

1.`name` - локализованное наименование

```
Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'RUB',
    currencyDisplay: 'name' 
}).format(1234567);
// "1 234 567 российских рублей"
```

2.`symbol` - локализованный символ

```
Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'RUB',
    currencyDisplay: 'symbol' 
}).format(1234567);
// "1 234 567 руб."
```

3.`code` - код калюты из ISO 4217

```
Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'RUB',
    currencyDisplay: 'code' 
}).format(1234567);
// "1 234 567 RUB"
```

Если все-таки необходимо что-то свое, то видимо придется использовать стороннюю библиотеку или оборачивать самостоятельно, например используя те же регулярные выражения.

Дополнительно наткнулся на [issue по спецификации](https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/4), который поднимает вопрос использования [нового символа для обозначения рубля](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_ruble#Currency_symbol), где одним из  вариантов решения было предоставление возможности установки собственного символа при вызове API, но в виду ограниченний спецификации этот вроде как отклонили. Поддержку нового символа для обозначения рубля обещают с сентября.